# APS workitem success webhook

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I want to register a evevt webhook that APS workitem completed successfully.
When I run AppScript code like the one below, I get a 400 error.

```js
function registerWebhook() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var token=sheet.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var bucket=sheet.getRange("C5").getValue(); 
  var apiEndpoint = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/webhooks/v1/systems/:system/hooks";
  var webhookData = {
    "hookUrl": "wss://53*****yb7.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/production/", 
    // Webフックを受信するURL
    "event": "workitem.completed",             // 監視するイベントの種類
    "system": "DesignAutomation",               // 監視対象のシステム
    "scope": "bucketKey:" + bucket // バケットキーを追加する 
  };
  
  var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
  };
  
  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": JSON.stringify(webhookData)
  };
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiEndpoint, options);
  
  if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    Logger.log("Webフックが正常に登録されました。");
  } else {
    Logger.log("Webフックの登録に失敗しました。");
    Logger.log("エラーコード:", response.getResponseCode());
    Logger.log("エラーメッセージ:", response.getContentText());
  }
}
```

Isn't there an API related to Design automation in the APS Webhook API?

Answer (score 1):

Design Automation has a slightly different mechanism. See the onComplete callback here: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/callbacks/